# Function of "about"- practised physiotherapy for about 6 months

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, adverb-position

> I practised physiotherapy *for* **about** 6 months.

- I understand that "about" can take forms such as an adv, adj,
  preposition.

Though I can rephrase the sentence, however, I am curious to find out what role "about" is playing in the above sentence.

- We already have a preposition "for", can we say that "about" is also
  in a **prepositinal role** or is it a different term for such placements
  of "**about'**.

Comment: It's an expression-of-measure modifier. In 'about 6 pies', it's a quantifier modifier.

Comment: OED: *The distinction between this prepositional use of **about** and the adverbial uses in sense A. III. has been slight in recent times. An expression such as **this animal is about the size of a rat** could be taken as containing the adverb, given that a quantitative noun phrase can appear as a complement without an introductory preposition (in, e.g., **this animal is the size of a rat** replacing earlier **this animal is of the size of a rat**), especially given that adverbial about can be introduced into a clause of the latter kind (e.g. **this animal is of about the size of a rat**).*

Comment: OED's Definition A. III: *Expressing approximation. With times and dates: near, close to, **at** approximately*. Where it always refers to a "calendar/clock date/time" (an actual point in time), rather than the ***duration*** of a time *period*.

Comment: It means *approximately six months*.